# The debugger is not ready

Tags: go, atom-editor, delve

I have installed *go-debug* package to my Atom on my Windows 10 machine, however I am getting "The debugger is not ready ..." message in Debug tab.

Can you please suggest how to resolve the same? Let me know if I need to fetch any further information.

[image]

Comment: Can someone please help me with any reference/solution?

Comment: You should talk a look at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/lloiser/go-debug/issues/100).